# Using methods on objects in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, object, image-processing

I am receiving a null pointer exception when trying to use a method on an object in a two dimensional array.

I am declaring the array like this:

```
Color[][] rgbArray = new Color[height][width];
```

It is obviously an array of color objects. I am then adding color objects to the array using:

```
for (int y = 0; y < (height); ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < (width); ++x) {

        rgbArray[y][x] = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
    }
}
```

This is using the rgb values from the buffered image "img" to create color objects at the appropriate array index.

I am then trying to access these values using something likes this:

```
for (int y = tempStartlimit; y < (tempEndlimit); ++y) {
    for (int x = tempStartlimit; x < (tempEndlimit); ++x) {

        int red += rgbArray[y][x].getRed();
        int green += rgbArray[y][x].getGreen();
        int blue += rgbArray[y][x].getBlue();
    }
}
```

Why is this not working?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What line of code is throwing the NPE? Is `img` perhaps `null`?

Comment: What is the value of tempStartlimit and tempEndlimit?

Comment: With such questions you want to post atleast the first few lines of the stack. Better yet, just look at them, you should be able to figure out yourself.

Comment: Can you specify what is not working?

Comment: `int red +=` shouldn't compile. Is it actually like that in your project or did you change the code before posting it here? (Make sure to post the real code.)

Comment: tempStartlimit = 0, tempEndlimit = 2.

Comment: No. Red is declared earlier in the code. Put 'int' to make its type clear. In the code it is just 'red += ...'

Comment: @fluffybonkers It is not making it clear, it is just adding to the confusion.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? My guess is you have a mistake like `Color[][] rgbArray;` declared as a field in the class and in the constructor you have `Color[][] rgbArray = new Color[height][width];` (which is a new declaration and hides the field) but it's impossible to tell with such a small snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `tempEndlimit` for both dimensions, but use `height` and `width` during initialization. Are you SURE that `tempEndLimit` is less than both? Else there is your answer. Did you mean to use 2 limits?

Comment: I believe so. I am trying to access the array in a series of 2x2 blocks e.g. access first 2 values in the first two columns in the first two rows. Then do it again for the next two columns in the first two rows etc.

Comment: The array is shown to be instantiated as `new Color[height][width]` so it's clear the array is entirely filled at least initially.

Comment: @fluffybonkers then perhaps your array is not even x even ? Or your logic for stoping at the edges is wrong. You need to look at the temp limits.

Comment: A problem with subscripts may cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but I don't see how it would cause a NPE.